# Can I design a UITableViewController with static content in the Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I'd like to use a UITableViewController to display some static content. Is it possible to design the entire table, including content, within Interface Builder, or is it always necessary to implement a data source, taking care of dequeing cells, etc?

I know there's Monotouch.Dialog, but for some things I would still prefer to use the IB.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing a data source will always be required.

The closest thing you can do to designing everything in IB, is to add and design your individual cells in the XIB (or in a separate XIB), adding the content you want, and use them in your data source through outlets.

Comment: I did not know that I can design several cells within a common XIB, so this definitely helps. Thanks!

Comment: Might be worth revising this answer to include details on storyboarding

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode 4.2 beta, a very crashy and rather undocumented new feature allows for storyboarding of your application, including static content within table views. I've been having trouble getting it to work at runtime, however. Still, this could change in the future, is what I'm saying. ;-)

Comment: This seems to be working pretty well, with Xcode 4.2 (release).

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I believe I first tried using it in May, and later in early August. I suppose by October it'd better be more stable as Lion matures and crashes are reported...